# Overlap of data of List in synchronized block

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety, locking

I have a method:

```
private List<String> userCns = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
private List<String> recipients = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

public void sendEmailToLegalUsers() {
    try {
        synchronized (lock) {
            searchGroup();

            if(userCns.size() > 0) {
                for(String userCn : userCns) {
                    String mail = getUserMail(userCn);
                    if(mail != null) {
                        recipients.add(mail);
                    }
                }                   
            }

            String docName = m_binder.getLocal("docname");
            String docId = m_binder.getLocal("docid");
            String url = m_binder.getLocal("serverURL");

            if(recipients.size() > 0) {
                m_binder.addResultSet("LOI_EVIN_MAIL", getLoiEvinMailResultSet(docName, docId, url));

                for(String recipient : recipients) {
                    Log.info("Sending mail to: " + recipient);
                    InternetFunctions.sendMailToEx(recipient, "MH_LOI_EVIN_SEND_EMAIL", "Update Evin Law Compliance for the item: " + docName, m_service, true);
                }
            }
        }           
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.info("Error occurred in LDAPSendMail: "+ e.getMessage());
    }   
}
```

Now this sendEmailToLegalUsers method can be called from different threads. I am wondering is it the right way to lock the code block so that there is no chances of data mixup in the list?

---

Edit: whole class:

```
package com.edifixio.ldapsendmail.handlers;

import intradoc.common.Log;
import intradoc.data.DataResultSet;
import intradoc.server.InternetFunctions;
import intradoc.server.ServiceHandler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class LDAPSendMail extends ServiceHandler {

    private final Object lock = new Object();

    private String ldapURL;
    private String baseDN;
    private String groupDN;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private DirContext context;

    private List<String> userCns = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
    private List<String> recipients = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

    public void sendEmailToLegalUsers() {
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                searchGroup();

                if(userCns.size() > 0) {
                    for(String userCn : userCns) {
                        String mail = getUserMail(userCn);
                        if(mail != null) {
                            recipients.add(mail);
                        }
                    }                   
                }

                String docName = m_binder.getLocal("docname");
                String docId = m_binder.getLocal("docid");
                String url = m_binder.getLocal("serverURL");

                if(recipients.size() > 0) {
                    m_binder.addResultSet("LOI_EVIN_MAIL", getLoiEvinMailResultSet(docName, docId, url));

                    for(String recipient : recipients) {
                        Log.info("Sending mail to: " + recipient);
                        InternetFunctions.sendMailToEx(recipient, "MH_LOI_EVIN_SEND_EMAIL", "Update Evin Law Compliance for the item: " + docName, m_service, true);
                    }
                }

                userCns.clear();
                recipients.clear();
            }           
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.info("Error occurred in LDAPSendMail: "+ e.getMessage());
        }   
    }

    private String getUserMail(String userCn) throws NamingException {
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResults = getLdapDirContext().search(userCn, "(objectclass=person)", getSearchControls());
        while (searchResults.hasMore()){
            SearchResult searchResult = searchResults.next();
            Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
            Attribute mail = null;

            try {
                mail = attributes.get("mail");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mail = null;
            }

            if(mail != null) {
                return (String)mail.get();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void searchGroup() throws NamingException {
        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResults = getLdapDirContext().search(groupDN, "(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)", getSearchControls());
        String searchGroupCn = getCNForBrand(m_binder.getLocal("brandId"), m_binder.getLocal("brandName"));

        while (searchResults.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult searchResult = searchResults.next();
            Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
            Attribute groupCn = null;

            try {
                groupCn = attributes.get("cn");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                groupCn = null;
            }

            if(groupCn != null) {
                if(searchGroupCn.equals((String)groupCn.get())) {
                    Attribute uniqueMembers = attributes.get("uniqueMember");
                    for(int i = 0; i < uniqueMembers.size(); i++){
                        String uniqueMemberCN = (String) uniqueMembers.get(i);
                        userCns.add(uniqueMemberCN);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private DirContext getLdapDirContext() throws NamingException {
        if(context != null) {
            return context;
        }

        ldapURL = m_binder.getLocal("ldapUrl");
        baseDN = m_binder.getLocal("baseDN");
        groupDN = new StringBuilder().append("ou=").append(getAccountGroup(m_binder.getLocal("account"))).append(",").append("ou=groups,").append(baseDN).toString();
        username = m_binder.getLocal("username");
        password = m_binder.getLocal("password");

        Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapURL);
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

        context = new InitialDirContext(environment);

        return context;
    }

    private SearchControls getSearchControls() {
        SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();       
        searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        return searchControls;
    }

    private String getCNForBrand(String brandId, String brandName) {        
        String[] brandIdSplittedArray = brandId.split("/");
        return new StringBuilder().append(brandIdSplittedArray[0]).append("-").append(brandIdSplittedArray[1]).append("-").
                append(brandIdSplittedArray[2]).append("-").append(brandName.replaceAll("\\s","")).append("-LU").toString();
    }

    private String getAccountGroup(String account) {        
        return account.split("/")[1];
    }

    private DataResultSet getLoiEvinMailResultSet(String docName, String docId, String url) {
        DataResultSet resultSet = new DataResultSet(new String[]{"DOCNAME", "DOCID", "URL"});
        Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
        vector.add(docName);
        vector.add(docId);              
        vector.add(url);
        resultSet.addRow(vector);
        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you define the `lock`? I would make the lists final and use one of those as the lock. In any case you should lock on a final field.

Comment: The lock is a field defined in that class where this method resides, `private final Object lock = new Object();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `lock`? Are you using it elsewhere? Typically you want the synchronized blocks to be pretty small. If you're using `lock` everywhere as a general purpose lock then you might be stopping a thread from doing some useful work in a totally unrelated area (i.e., one where there is no contention for shared resources).

Second, does `recipients` really need to be an instance variable? It seems strange that you would keep adding emails to `recipients` without checking to see if that email already exists in the list. I can't see any code where you're clearing our `recipients` either. So that is a potential issue. If you are going to be building `recipients` from scratch every time, then just make it a local variable in the method. If you really need access to that data, you can always pull it out of `userCns`.

Once you make `recipients` a local variable, then you only need to synchronize by using `userCns` as a lock:

```
synchronized(userCns) {
   ...
}
```

**edit:** Your code shows that you only use `recipients` once, and that's inside the `sendEmailToLegalUsers` method. Another thing, as I pointed out, is that you never clear `recipients` so that's a bug in your code. Since you don't use `recipients` anywhere, make it a local variable to `sendEmailToLEgalUsers`. Also, just synchronize over `userCns`. You won't need to synchronize over `recipients`; you can create it inside the synchronized block.

Comment: The lock is a field defined in that class where this method resides, `private final Object lock = new Object();`

Comment: You shouldn't need that and shouldn't be doing it that way anyway. Synchronize over the shared resource and not an arbitrary object.

Comment: I have provided the whole class, so that it will be helpful to help me. I need to get the email addresses from the ldap. The search is depends on some params passed into the.

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
private final List<String> userCns = new ArrayList<String>();
private final List<String> recipients = new ArrayList<String>();
```

with

```
synchronized(userCns) {
   // as Vivin suggests.
}
```

you don't need an additional lock.